# Bone moves weird

Tags: rigging, armature, pose-mode

When trying to move bones in pose mode some of the bones are moving in a sort of robotic motion where they are snapping to locations where I cannot move to the exact location I want. I can't really post this i an image but hoping someone can figure this out.

Comment: have you enabled the Snap option?

Comment: Where is that located?

Comment: 3d view > Header menu bar, the magnet icon

Comment: It worked. Thanks.